# How to make a special slider or jslider on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, slider, jslider

How to make a special slider (or jslider) with areas after minimum and maximum range on Matlab?
Please see the illustration:
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a custom Java control, using a custom paint() method. I suggest that you repost your question as a Java Swing question (tags Java, Swing, JSlider) - this should get you some responses. Then use the control in Matlab as usual.